# Include AVFoundation Framework in Theos application

Tags: ios, makefile, include, avfoundation, theos

I am writing an application for my iPhone 5 using Theos tools and I want to use AVFoundation framework.

I've included AVFoundation in FRAMEWORKS section of my Makefile:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

APPLICATION_NAME = appName
appName_FILES = main.m appNameApplication.mm RootViewController.mm StandardPlaybackVC.mm
appName_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit CoreGraphics AVFoundation

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/application.mk
```

But it doesn't seem to work and give the following error:

```
error: unknown type name 'AVAudioPlayer'
```

I've also tried to include this line in my header file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

But this gives a lot of confusing errors:

```
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVBase.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:75:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:680:2: error: 
      Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVBase.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:78:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVBase.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:79:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVBase.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/NSObjCRuntime.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:81:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h:37:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVBase.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include/limits.h:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioBuffer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioTypes.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:21:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/signal.h:63:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:81:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/signal.h:34:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioBuffer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioTypes.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:21:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/signal.h:63:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:145:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/_mcontext.h:31:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from RootViewController.mm:3:
In file included from ./StandardPlaybackVC.h:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioBuffer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioTypes.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFByteOrder.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSByteOrder.h:45:10: fatal error: 
      'libkern/machine/OSByteOrder.h' file not found
#include <libkern/machine/OSByteOrder.h>
         ^
8 errors generated.
```

I do not use #import pragmas for UIKit and Core Graphics so I thought that modifying the Makefile should be enough...

What am I doing wrong here? And what is the right way of including frameworks in Theos? I'm using iPhone SDK 8.1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had same error on my tweaks,but solved this error.
Cause is the StandardPlaybackVC file.
UIKit CoreGraphics AVFoundation,

Don't write all "#import Framework" in StandardPlaybackVC.